# A weakening of the topology axioms

Tags: general-topology, definition

A topology is a set of subsets satisfying certain axioms, including closure under arbitrary unions and finite intersections. Is there a term for the weakened structure given by changing closure under arbitrary unions to finite unions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure is just a lattice of sets, albeit with the restriction that it must contain the empty set. A lattice of sets is simply a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) whose join and meet are union and intersection, respectively.